# Using large objects in javascript- performance killer?

Tags: javascript, object

My Html:

```
<div class="my-module-1"><!-- Lot of stuff happens here--></div>
<div class="my-module-2"><!-- Lot of stuff happens here--></div>
<div class="my-module-3"><!-- Lot of stuff happens here--></div>
```

My JS:

```
var myobj1 = {
  somefunc1 function() { /* function code */ },
  somefunc2 function() { /* function code */ },
  somefunc3 function() { /* function code */ },
  somefunc4 function() { /* function code */ },
  // etc.
  prop1: "some string",
  prop2: "some string",
  prop3: [...],
  prop4: "some string",
  // etc.
};

var myobj2 = {
  somefunc1 function() { /* function code */ },
  somefunc2 function() { /* function code */ },
  somefunc3 function() { /* function code */ },
  somefunc4 function() { /* function code */ },
  // etc.
  prop1: "some string",
  prop2: "some string",
  prop3: [...],
  prop4: "some string",
  // etc.
};

var myobj3 = {
  somefunc1 function() { /* function code */ },
  somefunc2 function() { /* function code */ },
  somefunc3 function() { /* function code */ },
  somefunc4 function() { /* function code */ },
  // etc.
  prop1: "some string",
  prop2: "some string",
  prop3: [...],
  prop4: "some string",
  // etc.
};

// Init
myobj1.somefunc1();
myobj2.somefunc2();
myobj3.somefunc3();
myobj1.somefunc4();

// etc.
```

I tried to organize all the variables + functions belonging to my module in one object to get more structure in my code.

Is this a good way to do this?

Could this be a performance problem, using lots of large objects in my code?

I appreciate every kind of valuable input and opinion;)

Comment: If `obj1` and `obj2` and `obj3` have the same properties, you should create a constructor (class).

Comment: You ask about performance: this is something you can test yourself. Do you have a problem with performance being killed?

Comment: No this was just an example. the properties and methods are very specific and do not repeat.

Comment: I was told that large objects could be a performance killer, but at the moment I cannot confirm that. Therefore, my idea was to ask whether this is actually true in practice. I myself did not find any useful information while researching. Would it be better to work with constructor functions in general?

Comment: There is no problem with large objects. If you have lots of data and lots of functions, then anyway you need that memory and initialisation. So whether you store that (for instance) as globals, or as object properties is not going to impact performance that much. But for concrete cases there may be things that can be improved. As your question is very generic and not about a concrete implementation, there is not much else to say.

Comment: Yes i know that i appreciate your help and knowledge nevertheless! You helped me a lot. I was afraid that using objects in this way is in general not recommended an it helps me that this way is at least not totally an antipattern.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, using large objects can cause performance problems.

Large objects increase the bundle size of your application. If you are delivering a website, this affects the time it takes to download the application aswell as the duration of javascript parsing and compile tasks.
You can get a detailed view of those tasks by using a profiler tool, such as Chrome's performance tab.

Notice that this isn't specific to large objects in the sense that if you were to split it into smaller objects you would still have the issue mentioned above